When/where to declare goods with Global Entry?
From what I've seen, the way Global Entry works at one airport is:

You get off the plane, walk through the airport terminal, and go to the Global Entry kiosk

They take your photo

No questions are asked whatsoever

There's an officer standing there that then tells you you're good to go

You go pick up your checked baggage, if any

A bunch of officers are standing somewhere around the carousels with their dogs etc.

You leave the baggage area


Exactly at what point, and how, are you supposed to make a declaration the correct way?
(Note that the photo location comes before your baggage claim, so you wouldn't even necessarily have the goods with you at that point.)

Again, as with the previous question, Global Entry membership changes nothing. It only shortens the queue.

There's an officer standing there that then tells you you're good to go

Here.

A bunch of officers are standing somewhere around the carousels with their dogs etc.

Or here.
Either of these spots. These are the CBP officers, and they're the ones you declare stuff to. You can't exit the immigration checks without passing one, and in the US you can't exit the luggage area without passing another one. If you have anything to declare - you'll talk to them.
You don't need to have the goods to make the declaration, but if they want to see the goods they'll ask you to grab the luggage.

I've only regularly flown into LAX and the customs checkpoint is after you pick up your bags (and after you pass through immigration).  And I doubt it could be done any other way as it would be hard to declare stuff and have it inspected before you collected your bags.

@PeterM in the US the customs and the immigration are the same people. So yes, you can do the declaration before you collect the bags, in fact that's when they actually ask you if you have anything to declare.

I've only handed in my customs declaration card when exiting the baggage collection area.

Haven't flown through LAX in a while, but in SFO they haven't been using paper cards for years now.

I last flew into LAX in 2017 so it's likely that it's changed.  And I bet covid would have helped with that.

@PeterM For what it’s worth ATL, ORD, IAD, and DTW also have customs after baggage claim as well. In fact, the same i true of every airport I’ve been through in Europe as well. But at least in the US, you can declare goods to any CBP officer from passport control up through the actual checkpoint, you’ll just be directed where to go for the formal declaration (and inspection if required). But I would personally opt to declare early if I needed to declare anything, since it makes it less likely I’ll need to backtrack (also, if you don’t have GE, they usually ask at passport control anyway).
